# Is Bayesian hyperparameter tuning algorithm supported in Google ML Engine?

Tags: google-cloud-ml

According to https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/reference/rest/v1/projects.jobs#Algorithm there are only grid search and random search algorithms available.

According to this blog post https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/hyperparameter-tuning-cloud-machine-learning-engine-using-bayesian-optimization Bayesian is supported.

So, if supported, how can I tune hyperparameters using Bayesian optimization on Google Cloud ML Engine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you leave the algorithm set to default, it will use Bayesian optimization (see [docs](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/hyperparameter-tuning-overview#search_algorithms)).

Comment: More details about supported algorithms are documented in :https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/hyperparameter-tuning-overview#search_algorithms. And it mentions that the default algorithm uses bayesian optimization.